# Avoid un-highlighting of Twitter's Bootstrap dropmenu items when clicking outside the menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I noticed a strange behavior in bootstrap dropmenus: when the user clicks anywhere outside the dropmenu, any highlighted item that has been clicked on previously looses it's highlighting.

you can see that in the following link: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns

clicking on the item named 'Action' will highlight it, and then clicking anywhere outside will remove the highlighting.

I suppose this is by design - even though I don't understand the logic: once I click on an item in a dropmenu I wish it to become deselected only when clicking on ANOTHER item - not outside the menu.

Any suggestions as to how to avoid this behavior?  I've tried using stopPropogation on any click - but it doesn't work.

Thanks !

Comment: The style is applied to the :focus state, that's why it looses highlighting when clicking anywhere else. Try giving a class to your menu items on click with the same style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this behavior will be strange.
The highlight is set by the focus of the link. Clicking else where remove the focus and so the styling (highlighting).

To change this behavior add a css class to link on focus (ans remove this class for previous focused links). Give this css class the same styling as the highlight classes.

**example html**:

```
<div class="dropdown clearfix">
              <ul style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#1" tabindex="-1">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2" tabindex="-1">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3" tabindex="-1">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#4" tabindex="-1">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
</div>
```

**css for the the class to add** (called focused):

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a.focused
{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  outline: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
```

**javascript**:

```
$('.dropdown li a').focus(function(){
     $('.dropdown li a').removeClass('focused');
     $(this).addClass('focused');       

     });
```

Example / demo:  http://bootply.com/66106

Comment: thank you very much !  it works great and I learnt from your solution how I should have approached this initially.  Thanks again !